# Deeply nested routes in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got this in my `show.html.erb`:

```
<%= link_to "Pay on this contract", new_product_contract_payment_path %>
```

And this in `routes.rb`

```
  resources :products do
    resources :contracts do
      resources :payments 
    end
  end
```

But when I view the contract page, I get this error:

`No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"payments"}`

The route shows up when I use `rake routes` and the payments controller is there. This is my new method in the payments controller.

```
 def new
    @contract = Contract.find(params[:contract])
    @payment = @contract.line_items.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @payment }
    end
  end
```

Any thoughts on what's throwing the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass in a contract and a product, so something like:

```
 new_product_contract_payment_path(@product, @contract)
```

Comment: I should've mentioned I did try that and get this error: `No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"payments", :product_id=>nil, :contract_id=>#<Contract id: 17, product_id: 4, author_id: 1, begins: "2011-01-14", ends: "2012-01-14", created_at: "2011-01-14 01:49:02", updated_at: "2011-01-14 01:49:02">}`